# task queue in Appengine (using NDB) stopping another function from updating data

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

```
cred_query = credits_tbl.query(ancestor=user_key).fetch(1)

for q in cred_query:
    q.total_credits = q.total_credits + credits_bought
    q.put()
```

I have a task running which is constantly updating a users total_credits in the credits table.

While that task runs the user can also buy additional credits at any point (as shown in the code above) to add to the total. However, when they try to do so, it does not update the total_credits in the credits table.

I guess I don't understand the 'strongly consistent' modelling of appengine (using ndb) as well as I thought.

Do you know why this happens?

Comment: Is that it for the code.  Is this piece wrapped in a transaction - and for that matter is the user's buy credit's wrapped in a transaction ?  If not then that is most likely your problem. Out of order updates.

Comment: Thank you, that is actually the right direction - wrapping it in a transaction. it frightens me how little I know when building a currently running business application. I was going to say 'my lack of sleep' and that would be a lie.

Comment: Yep, that solved it, thanks Tim. The background process was writing to the entity regularly and splitting off part of the credits update function and making it transactional worked.